# How to express when there is no value in the Flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Among the values stored in the Flutter Firestore is a timestemp called "user_last_update_time".
This value is generated only when the user last updates the user profile.
At this time, I wanted to express the time when the user last updated the user profile, so I wrote the code as below.

```
user_last_update_time(){
                            var numberTomonthMap = {
                              1 : '1month',
                              2 : '2month',
                              3 : '3month',
                              4 : '4month',
                              5 : '5month',
                              6 : '6month',
                              7 : '7month',
                              8 : '8month',
                              9 : '9month',
                              10 : '10month',
                              11 : '11month',
                              12 : '12month',
                            };

                            Timestamp t = data['user_last_update_time'] as Timestamp;
                            DateTime date = t.toDate();
                            return '${date.year}year ${numberTomonthMap[date.month]!} ${date.day}day ${date.hour}hour ${date.minute}minute ${date.second}second';
                          }
```

```
Text('profile_last_update_time : ' + user_last_update_time(), style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
```

After creating it like this, if the value "user_last_update_time" is in the firestore, it works fine.

However, if the value "user_last_update_time" is not present, the following error occurs.

```
The following StateError was thrown building:
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
```

I tried to code as below to solve this, but I couldn't

```
if(user_last_update_time().isEmpty)
 Text('Last profile change time : Not changed', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                
if(Jiujitsu_user_last_update_time().isNotEmpty)
 Text('Last profile change time : ' + user_last_update_time(), style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
```

How do I solve this?
What I want is to indicate the timestemp if there is a value of "user_last_update_time" in the firestore, and if there is no value, I want to display "Not Change".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if( data['user_last_update_time'] == null ){do soemthing...};
```

or when retrieving data try this to get an empty string when its null

```
data['user_last_update_time'] ?? '';
```

let me know in the comments if this works or not to give you more solutions